# Core Doctrine vs Common Practices

Tags: discussion

In a comment to an [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/16851/671) on my question, Maiwa noted that

> [particular theology] is not always a part of core doctrines of any denomination. It's about what the majority of the denomination believe

So when asking questions of the form "Is X practiced by any denominations/'mainline' denominations" or similar questions, should we differentiate between core doctrines and common practices?

(I considered rephrasing and asking on the main site, but I figured it fit better here)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is so much an issue for wording questions as it is for answers. This is one area where even if they do a little bit of homework before asking, somebody asking may not know what answer to expect. On the other hand, an expert in that particular issue or denomination will know how to break down the documented core doctrines vs. common practices. Any answer worth it's salt would give some indication as to where they stand on both counts.

I think this is a major shortcoming of the answer you linked as an example. The question was about where a denomination stands on an issue. If there is, as their comments indicate, a major disparity in the official denominational position vs. the individual regions and what is being taught in pulpits, that would be relevant information to include in an answer.

Comment: Yes, expecting the questioner to be able to figure this out before hand is too high a bar. (and I'm a high bar kinda guy)

Comment: Okay, so just asking about "Core Doctines OR Common Practices" sounds like the way to go then. Thanks!